# gettext from edittext inside OnClicklistener doesn't work in android

Tags: android, onclicklistener

Why can't i access the text from edittext via gettext

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(name.getText().toString() != "") {
            }
```

It says name has to be declared final. if so i cannot run the programm. Click doesn't work or application stops.

Comment: EditText name = new EditText(this); before the code

Comment: add full code of that

Comment: Use like this ->  if(!name.getText().toString().equalignorecase("")) {<YOUR CODE>}

Comment: make your button Final

Comment: show your error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your **EditText and Button as global** and **initialize** it

In java, when using == on two objects, you're not actually comparing the strings themselves. You'll need to use .equals(String) or .equalignorecase(String).

== actually compares the two object's references, not their values.

string1.equals(String target) compares the two strings based off of the actual characters in the strings.

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(name.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to be declared final inside the onCreate method, not above the onCreate mothed to get rid of all errors.

Answer (score -1):

Either declare your edittext as **final** or as **global**.

Moreover, you should **never** use `!=` for string comparison. It is prone to error. Change :

```
if(name.getText().toString() != "")
```

to :

```
if(!name.getText().toString().equals(""))
```

or in this specific case since what you actually care about is the string **not being empty**, you can use :

```
if(!name.getText().toString().isEmpty())
```